# Skip youtube-dl download when live stream has not been trimmed yet

Tags: youtube-dl

I was looking for a `--match-filter` on `youtube-dl` that would let me detect if a video id was originally livestreamed, and if so has the author applied a trim to the original video.  All I could find was the `is_live` filter.

Basically, I want to skip over such videos which have not yet been trimmed.

I've ran the `--dump-json` command on a few sample video ids; one during a livestream, one after a livestream finished, and one after a livestream is trimmed.  But I can't see any field that would identify this?

Any ideas?

Comment: How can you as a human determine if the video was livestreamed or trimmed - is there any indication on the YouTube website? If yes, then youtube-dl can be extended to return that information, or filter by it. But if it's a case of "I saw that video on twitch already, and it was the same length there", then it's really not feasible without significant artificial intelligence to evaluate whether the video was livestreamed and trimmed.

Comment: YouTube does state how long ago it was live-streamed in the header of the video description.  So I assume YouTube-dl could at least pull in that info?

Comment: Here’s a example one: https://youtu.be/RqaSvFqF3Lw.  Normally the header says “published on dd mmm yyyy”. But this one says “streamed live on dd mmm yyyy”

Comment: @phihag, forgot to target the previous comments at you.  See above.  Is this something that can be formally requested?

Comment: Sure, you can request it, at https://yt-dl.org/bugs . I'd leave out the part about the trimming and suggest a name and use case for the new property. As somebody else is now maintaining youtube-dl, I cannot say whether your suggestion will be adapted.